# What's the difference between "cause and effect" and "premiss and conclusion"?

Tags: logic

I'm reading a book titled the *Elements Of Logic* and there is a portion which tries to differentiate between "cause and effect" and "premiss and conclusion".

I don't get the distinctions made in the follow excerpts.

> If I say, "this ground is rich because the trees are flourishing" or
> "the trees are flourishing therefore the ground is rich".

These are considered premisses and conclusions.

> If I say, "the ground is rich and therefore the trees flourish" or
> "the trees flourish because the ground is rich".

These are considered causes and effects.

What is the difference?

Comment: *Cause* and *effect* are terms of a "causal process", between *events* in the world. *Premise* and *conclusion* are assertions linked by an *argument* and are linguistic "entities".

Comment: Maybe its better to write that part of the book

Comment: When we use the argument: "Every man is mortal; Socrates is a man. Therefore: Socrates is mortal" the conclusion ("Socrates is mortal") is a *consequence* of the two premises. But the cause (one of ?) of the *mortality* of Socrates is its DNA structure.

Comment: Maybe you are alluding at the "tricky" way to read "if $A$, then $B$" as "$B$ is a *necessary condition* for $A$" ...

Answer (score 3):

*Cause and effect* is a much stronger requirement than *premise and conclusion*. To say that $A$ "caused" $B$ is to say that there is some sort of connection between $A$ and $B$ that brought $B$ into being. To say that $B$ *follows from* $A$ (as a conclusion follows from a premise) is to say that whenever $A$ is true, $B$ happens to be true also. This could be for *entirely unrelated* reasons.

For example, consider the following argument:

```
 Premise: The moon is made of green cheese.
 Conclusion: Either the sun is yellow or the sun is not yellow.
```

The conclusion is always true, so whenever the premise happens to be true the conclusion is as well. That makes this a perfectly *valid* argument. But it would be ludicrous to say that lunar dairy had anything to do with the color of the sun!

Now, a common response to this is "well, that's a terrible definition of *consequence*; shouldn't we require that, in arguments, the conclusion should always be related to the premises?" But remember, this is math, so we need to be able to precisely define things - how do you define "related"? It's not obvious that you can. So we just give up and say "okay, fine, they don't need to be related after all."

Answer (score 0):

"The belief in the cause-effect relationship is akin to superstition", L. Wittgenstein, a deep and witty statement on how the cause and effect concepts are completely alien to the world of logic.
 They are anthropomorpic ideas, linked to the fact something (the "effect") could or could not happen, depending upon something else (the "cause") occurred or not. If you compare this to the fact that a mathematical premise-conclusion, the difference might be evident.

This might also reflected in our everyday, informal language. When we say that a car accident caused an injury, we implicitly recognise that, while the car accident had a great impact on the effect, the latter was not necessary: there are accident that do not result in injuries, which makes the information valuable. At the end of the day, the statement "X is dead, and as a result is not among us any more" would raise a few eyebrows.

Also, we tend to place cause and effect in a clear temporal sequence whereby cause precedes  the effect, while the hypothesis and thesis in a mathematical theorem are, in some sense, simultaneous. "Two natural numbers are odd" implies "their sum is even": the conclusion does not occur "after" the premise: it is inevitable, it is a manifestation of the same fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences, so it is hard to know what the book is after ... maybe you can include a relevant passage from the book in your post?

Anyway, here is one big difference I see:

Cause and effect is typically something true of the *natural* world. Our world that is. Thus, we can say something like 'rain causes things to get wet'.

In reasoning, however (which is where we talk about premisses and a conclusion), we say that an argument is valid if and only if the conclusion *logically* follows from the premises, and that means that we look at all possible worlds, most of which are quite unlike ours.

Thus, we can say that 'If it rains, then things get wet' is a conditional that expresses a causal relationship that is true in our world, but the argument:

'It rains. Therefore, things will get wet' is not considered a logically valid inference.

Answer (score 0):

basically premises and conclusion, in any valid argument (not to be confused with a sound argument), allows you to say if the premises are taken to be true so must the conclusion. Cause and effect suffers the [fallacy](https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/wi-phi/wiphi-critical-thinking#wiphi-fallacies) of "post hoc, ergo propter hoc" which simply means it's based on the assumed premise that cause come before effect. So I punch the sky, the sun suddenly explodes. We could claim that because my punch to the sky happened before the sun exploded it was the cause. Now it's unlikely, because we have other more ampliative arguments, in our knowledge base already. To truly be a cause of something, it would have to be the only explanation that works.

Answer (score 0):

*Long comment*

Part of the misunderstandig is due to the words used: in natural language, "because" is usually used to express a cause-effect relationship while "therefore" is used to express an inference.

When we assert:

> "the trees flourish because the ground is rich"

we are asserting that the richness of the ground is the cause that produces the flourishing of the trees, and this is reasonable.

When we assert:

> "the trees are flourishing, therefore the ground is rich"

we are making an inference. From the effect: we see that the trees are flourishing, we infer the cause: that the ground is rich.

Answer (score 0):

> Premise : "Icecream sales have increased, and sunburn rates increase whenever they do."
>
> Conclusion: "Therefore sunburn rates will increase".

This is a logically valid argument, and can be quite sound, but would you suggest that icecream sales cause sunburn?

> Cause: "When it is summer at the beach, it is hot and sunny ..." 
>
>  Effect: "... people will buy more icecream, and sunbath more often."